# Add custom text to certain pages

Tags: 7

To add custom text to a node I have a code like this:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $var=....;
  if (.....) ){
      $node->content['new'] = array(
       '#markup' => $var,
     );
  }
}
```

It works perfectly, but now I need to add this text to pages that don't load any node. So I can't use this hook.

I mean something like the drupal_set_message function, showing custom text at the top of certain pages.

Comment: In order to override or insert variables into the page templates, you can use [template_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add this to your if condition:

```
if($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)){
   //your code here
 }
```

Comment: When I access pages that don't load any node (that is where I need show the text), the hook I am using (hook_node_view()) doesn't execute, so your solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your text inside a block, then assigning it to a region? [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) is useful for assigning blocks to regions based on a variety of conditions.

Comment: My text changes depending the page you access, so I think I can't use a block to do that. Can I?

Comment: You can: One of the conditions the module has is the path of the page being shown.

Answer (score 0):

I would use panels and [panels everywhere](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere) for that.
You can actually just create custom text panes and add to any page.

To get started with these two modules I can recommend the [videos by cojanti](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6zMcfTxkhc)

Block and Context as mentioned above is also possible but we never use that since blocks are not deployable so easy.